# A tool to export images (photos) in a folder hierarcy on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone-app, image-viewer, ipad-app

I've tried to import photos from my computer to my iPad (Air 2), and they just end up in an album, all together. But in my computer they're all in different folders nicely organized. I would like to keep this organization in albums.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it's not possible to do that with iOS ?

If not (because I couldn't I'm asking here and not somewhere else) : is there a tool, an app, that would make me able to do that?

A very simple file explorer that would allow me to browse pictures, only pictures, saved locally on the ipad, that I have previously imported. The app/tool has to work offline.

If I have that I'm 100% happy, I won't mind extra features from the app.

Also if you know how to do this with the classic "Albums" then i'm all ears, but then this question wouldn't be relevant on this stackExchange website.

Answer (score 1):

I use Readdle's Documents 5. Its free and feature full not just for photos but all kind of documents. Also works as extension to other apps and with cloud when you want to.